# Excel - Match IDs across 2 sheets and then evaluate if the returned record date is within 7 days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got 2 separate datasets on separate sheets in Excel. Both contain 2 columns containing a Patient ID number (Col 1) and an Admission Date (col2)

I want to add a third column into dataset 1 to flag if a patient in Sheet 1 matches to a patient occurring on any row in Sheet 2 AND has an Admission date that occurred within 7 days of the admission date on sheet 1.

Effectively this:

```
*************************Sheet 1*******************************$**************Sheet 2************
                                                               $
| PATIENT ID | ADMISSION DATE | READMISSION WITHIN 7 DAYS? |   $   | PATIENT ID | ADMISSION DATE | 
+------------+----------------+----------------------------+   $   +------------+----------------+
|   1234     |   13/01/2017   |              Y             |   $   |   1200      |   02/12/2016   |
|   1235     |   16/01/2017   |              N             |   $   |   1234     |   16/01/2017   |
|   1236     |   17/01/2017   |              N             |   $   |   1236     |   27/01/2017   |
                                                               $
```

I've written the following formula to try and match the Patient ID to any occurrence in Sheet 2, and to then evaluate if the admission date in Sheet 1 is within 7 days prior to the admission date in Sheet 2. However, whilst it appears to match the Patient ID correctly, I can't get the second part of the argument to work, which is to compare the dates from the selected rows:

```
=IF(AND(B2<Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B2>Sheet2!B2-8*(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A2)=1)),"Y","N")
```

Please can anyone advise on a formula that will work?

Answer (score 0):

USE VLOOKUP to return the date, then compare it to the current:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ABS(B2-VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))<=7,"Y","N"),"N")
```

The data on Sheet2 must be ordered by date descending(with the most current on top).

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner - Apologies, tested this a little further and noticed that although it correctly flags where the date in Sheet2 occurs within 7 days after the date in Sheet1, it also flags those dates in Sheet2 that occurred within 7 days EARLIER than the date in Sheet1. Is it possible to restrict the formula to only evaluate in 1 direction please?

Comment: Remove the `ABS(B2-VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))` and replace with `AND(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)-B2<=7,VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)-B2>=0)`